# Differentiability and tangent relationship

Tags: limits, derivatives

(1) We say that if a function at $x=a$ is differentiable, then there exists a tangent.

(2) But if a function have tangent at $x=a$, then it may not be differentiable at $x=a$.

Also, when secants are becoming parallel to each other as $h\rightarrow 0$, the secants approaches to a common tangent at that point.
We use this condition to prove that a function is differentiable or not, i.e. LHD=RHD (have a tangent at that point). But in (2) , we have said that it may not be differentiable.

Make it clear to me ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  We are ready here to help you, but writing sentences like "Make it clear to me ASAP" would make potential helpers rather lukewarm (your question was already downvoted, not by me).  See [Be nice](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 0):

An endpoint can have a tangent but is not differentiable because the graph/function is not continuous at the endpoint.